# Magento2 migration steps from 2.3.x Open Source to Commerce

Tags: magento2.3, migration, magento-2-commerce, opensource

I have been searching about this process (the **technical part about a migration of Open Source 2.3 project to Commerce version**), but there is not too much info out there. At same time, the official resource about this seems so basic https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/upgrader/ce-ee-upgrade-start.html (without having yet the Magento Commerce access)

I have read somewhere you cannot use some 3rd party modules in Commerce version... First question would be: is it correct? If so, then I have lot of doubts at this point

This is purely because of code differences (code which exists in Commerce core version, but it doesn't in Open Source version), or is it some kind of legal thing about modules licensing?

Is there any way or tool to test that upgrade process to have a preview about errors we'll face & be able to plan something to fix them?

Any way to know which modules (apart from the Marketplace ones) we'd need to remove / rewrite?

Apart from the code  differences, is there any other requirement about coding quality (such as including testing, etc...) to have a module working in Commerce version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.I have read somewhere you cannot use some 3rd party modules in Commerce version... First question would be: is it correct? If so, then I have lot of doubts at this point

===== Yes it possible and that is depend on the different vendor how they developed the extension.

2.This is purely because of code differences (code which exists in Commerce core version, but it doesn't in Open Source version), or is it some kind of legal thing about modules licensing?

===== You can check the vendor extension policy for this one.

3. Is there any way or tool to test that upgrade process to have a preview about errors we'll face & be able to plan something to fix them?

===== Yes, you can create stage website and try to upgrade that one.

4. Any way to know which modules (apart from the Marketplace ones) we'd need to remove / rewrite?

Apart from the code differences, is there any other requirement about coding quality (such as including testing, etc...) to have a module working in Commerce version?

====== The only way is after doing the migration you need to test the extension, so you get idea.

Comment: So, we cannot get an idea of which modules will work until we get the commercial access & try the migration. Is it?

Comment: Yes, either you can check it in development environment.

Comment: You mean we can try composer require XXX without having the commercial access yet? Or that development environment is provided by Adobe / Magento?

Comment: No I mean development server of your commerce edition website.